# htaccess forward slash before domain error /www

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

My site URL structure is showing in search results as  "/www.domain.com"  (with a forward slash before www)

I believe the problem is with the htaccess file. Does anyone know a fix?
htaccess code is below. Many thanks.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ %2$1.php [QSA,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^kentuckycartitleloans.com 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.kentuckycartitleloans.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
RewriteRule ^.*about.php$ %2contact.php [QSA,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
RewriteRule ^.*online-application.php$ %2apply.php [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Comment: is `RewriteBase / RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f ` supposed to all be on one line?

Comment: ...Although if those two directives were together on one line you'd get an instant 500 error?! But, if the domain in question is the one in the middle of your .htaccess file then I don't see the slash prefix in the search results?!

Comment: "RewriteBase / " is on a separate line in the .htaccess file.  (It's incorrect in the code I pasted in). Yes the problematic domain is kentuckycartitleloans.com

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you are seeing? I can't see anything unusual in the search results for this domain? Presumably the URL that is indexed is correct, or does this also have an additional slash - does this resolve correctly? Do you have any browser extensions that might manipulate the page? Try a different browser.

Comment: The landing page is displaying on Google Analytics as "/www.kentuckycartitleloans*" http://screencast.com/t/E5akUiME